# Fedora 32: KVM routed Bridge Network

Tags: kvm-virtualization, fedora, libvirt, hetzner

I'm fighting with the following problem.

- I got an Hetzner dedicated Server with multiple additional IPs which I want to use for KVM VMs. (MainIP = 1.1.1.1, First additional IP: 2.2.2.2)
- Before my server was running Ubuntu 16.04 and acts as a router for the VMs. So every VM had its own public IPv4 and the gateway was the host itself. This was working very well!

I followed this:
https://wiki.hetzner.de/index.php/Netzkonfiguration_CentOS

and

https://wiki.hetzner.de/index.php/KVM_mit_Nutzung_aller_IPs_aus_Subnetz

How can I do that with Fedora 32 using Firewalld, Nftables and NetworkManager enabled?
I tried following the guide and adapting the commands for Fedora. At the moment I got one VM running on br0 Host-Device.

**KVM-Diagram 1**

[image: KVM-Diagram 1]

**KVM-Diagram 2**

[image: KVM-Diagram 2]

Comment: Go to the first link and skip most everything and go directly to «3 Zusätzliche IP-Adressen (Virtualisierung)». Use the «Routed (brouter)» instructions. There are several other ways to do this, including ones not listed in the Hetzner wiki, but this is the easiest and doesn't break IPv6. The configuration you describe having before corresponds to the «Bridged» section, so you could do that as well. But you have to get MAC addresses out of the Robot to use. I don't use or recommend it because it breaks IPv6 for the VMs, and since it's the 21st century, everyone needs to be using IPv6.

Comment: Hi, yes i tried following this part but it did not work, even if i have systemctl stop firewalld... any other ideas? I attached two screenshots which shows my setup.

Comment: i think i got it working now. but can i also add multiple bridges with the same host ip?

Comment: You only need one bridge. All the VMs can use it.

Comment: Okay,got it thank you! But is it also possible to have an bridge for every KVM? SO i can create separate firewall zones